# How can I use aria2c to convert magnet link to .torrent file while changing .torrent file name?

Tags: text-processing, bittorrent

I am using [aria2c](https://aria2.github.io/) to convert a magnet link to a .torrent file with the following command:

```
aria2c --bt-metadata-only=true --bt-save-metadata=true <MAGNET_LINK>
```

However it returns a really messy filename. Is there any way I can change the output of the torrent file?

I tried using `--dir=./ --index-out=1=MYTORRENT.torrent`, but that didn't work.

Comment: A few questions, if I may: A) Which version number of Ubuntu? B) Regular desktop, server, or a 'flavour'? (http://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) Please click edit to answer; please don't use Add Comment, as Comments have almost no formatting.

Comment: Check [this issue](https://github.com/aria2/aria2/issues/1435)

Answer (score 1):

No, as per the man page. The name is always the btih field of the magnet link.

```
--bt-save-metadata [true|false]
      Save meta data as ".torrent" file. This option has effect only when BitTorrent Magnet URI is used.  The file name is hex encoded info hash with suffix ".torrent". The directory to be saved is the same directory where download file is saved. If the same file already exists, meta data is not saved. See also --bt-metadata-only option. Default: false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aria2c --follow-torrent=false "your magnet link"
```

will save the torrent file your magnet link linked to and not download the files listed in the torrent.